# how to make a Short top app bar using material design?

Tags: android, material-design, toolbar, material-components-android

Fortnightly’s short top app bar: Material Design

On the scroll, the top app bar collapses to become a short top app bar, allowing more space for content. The short top app bar contains...

The short top app bar contains two elements: the navigation icon to open the navigation drawer, and the Fortnightly logo.

I found this guideline in material design io site, **could anyone share your idea, how to make this using material design, not 3rd party plugin.**

[image: Fortnightly’s short top app bar: Material Design]

Answer (score 1):

This is done using a [`MaterialShapeDrawable` with a `ShapeAppearanceModel`](https://blog.octo.com/en/android-materialshapedrawable/). You can also check the [source code for the toolbar](https://github.com/ologe/fortnightly/blob/b29f0aa845ee41b81bc01661a9ca739c6e940cda/app/src/main/java/dev/olog/fortnightly/presentation/widget/FortnightlyToolbar.kt#L45).